# How I can read an xml file in order to hang it as a marker to Mapview Android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

How can I read an XML file and then take over the individual items as markers in an overlay.

Here is an example of my XML files.

```
<marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant"/>
<marker name="Mama's Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar"/>
<marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant"/>
```

I'm still a newbie in Java / Android but nowhere can I find a guide.
I hope you can help me further.

Answer (score 1):

See [Working with XML in Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/),
[Hello Map View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)